# setuid bash script and binfmt_misc credentials flag

Tags: linux, bash, interpreter, setuid

In asking this question, I'm not looking to be told that I shouldn't be doing this or that it's insecure. Those matters beyond the scope of this question.

Linux respects the `setuid` and`setgid` bits on scripts when they are registered in the binfmt_misc filesystem with the credentials flag (`C`). [This](https://www.sentinelone.com/blog/shadow-suid-privilege-persistence-part-2/) is a demonstration of just that. I'm attempting to use this same facility to make shell scripts, specifically bash scripts, that will work with `setuid`/`setgid`. To this end, I crafted a binfmt string that employs file extension matching:

```
:pbash:E::pbash::/bin/bash:C
```

To test this, a file named `test.pbash` that lacks a shebang line, is owned by root, and has the mode 6755:

```
echo "Effective UID: $(id -u)"
echo "Real UID: $(id -ru)"
```

Running `test.pbash` outputs this:

```
Effective UID: 1000
Real UID: 1000
```

The effective UID should be displaying 0, so I had to search the web about `bash` and effective UIDs. I found that `bash` will change the effective UID to the real UID unless it is run with the `-p` flag set. This requires that I change the binfmt and create a wrapper script.

The wrapper script, `/bin/pbash`, with several invocations of `-p` just in case:

```
#!/bin/bash -p
set -p
exec bash -p -- "$@"
```

Delete the old binfmt and load the new new binfmt string:

```
:pbash:E::pbash::/bin/pbash:C
```

Run `test.pbash` and I get:

```
Effective UID: 1000
Real UID: 1000
```

Still not working. I figured I'd rewrite `/bin/pbash` to output some information:

```
#!/bin/bash -p
set -p
echo "Executing '$0' '$1'" > /tmp/log.txt
exec bash -p -- "$@"
```

I run `test.pbash` again and `/tmp/log.txt` doesn't exist, as if `/bin/pbash` didn't run at all. I remove the `C` flag from the binfmt string, run `test.pbash` again, and get the same output. What's changed is that `/tmp/log.txt` exists! It says:

```
Executing '/bin/pbash' '/bin/test.pbash'
```

So my wrapper script isn't even running when I have the credentials flag set. Why is `bash` or Linux behaving like this? How do I coerce it to run the wrapper script?

Answer (score -1):

The [kernel doc page](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/binfmt-misc.html) has a hint that might be important:

```
If you want to pass special arguments to your interpreter, you can
write a wrapper script for it ....
```

You might be running into one or both of two issues:

- an interpreter `/bin/bash -p` might be being taken literally as looking for a file called `"/bin/bash\ -p"`
- `echo "Effective UID: $(id -u)"` is **not** the same as `echo -n "Effective UID: " ; id -u`.

  - Specifically, the `$(id -u)` invokes `id` from within another invocation of `/bin/bash` (likely without a `-p` argument).

I've not drilled down to a minimal example, but this combination works for me. You might be able to trim it down to something shorter, but this gives an example that addresses both of the above potential issues: Try this code (`pbash.c`) as the interpreter:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    char **args = calloc(sizeof(char *), argc+2);
    memcpy(args+2, argv+1, (argc-1)*sizeof(char *));
    args[0] = strdup("bash");
    args[1] = strdup("-p");
    execv("/bin/bash", args);
    perror("exec failed");
}
```

Compile and install it:

```
$ gcc -o pbash pbash.c
$ sudo cp pbash /usr/local/bin/
$ ls -l /usr/local/bin/pbash
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 24832 Jul 16 21:35 /usr/local/bin/pbash
$ sudo -s
# echo ':pbash:E::pbash::/usr/local/bin/pbash:C' > /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc/register
# exit
$ ls -l /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc/
total 0
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 0 Jul 16 21:29 pbash
--w-------. 1 root root 0 Jul 16 21:29 register
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 0 Jul 16 20:55 status
```

And prepare a `try.pbash` script:

```
echo -n "Effective UID: " ; id -u
echo -n "Real UID: " ; id -ru
```

and make it `setuid` and run it:

```
$ sudo chown root.root  try.pbash
$ sudo chmod +xs try.pbash
$ ls -l try.pbash
-rwsr-sr-x. 1 root root 64 Jul 16 21:52 try.pbash
$ ./try.pbash
Effective UID: 0
Real UID: 1000
```